# SKAction not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

I have a sequence of SKActions that I would like to play but they do not play properly. The eye only closes and never opens again. I have no clue why this is occurring but maybe you do! Help is appreciated, thank you.

```
-(void)blink {

    SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
    SKAction *blinkEye = [SKAction resizeToHeight:1 duration:.2];
    SKAction *delay2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:.5];
    SKAction *openEye = [SKAction resizeToHeight:3 duration:.2];

    SKAction *group1 = [SKAction group:@[delay,blinkEye]];
    SKAction *group2 = [SKAction group:@[delay2,openEye]];

    SKAction *all = [SKAction sequence:@[group1,group2]];

    SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:all];

    [self runAction:repeat];

}
```

In MyScene.m

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
 /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    Player *player = (Player *)[self childNodeWithName:@"player"];
    Player *lefteye = (Player *)[player childNodeWithName:@"leye"];
    Player *righteye = (Player *)[player childNodeWithName:@"reye"];
    [lefteye blink];
    [righteye blink];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for grouping, it's causing the problem.

```
SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
SKAction *blinkEye = [SKAction resizeToHeight:1 duration:.2];
SKAction *delay2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:.5];
SKAction *openEye = [SKAction resizeToHeight:3 duration:.2];

SKAction *all = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,blinkEye, delay2,openEye]]];
```

And letting blink the eye on every frame update can't work. This function is called up to 60 times a second.

Instead do it like this on creation of the eye object:

```
SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
SKAction *blinkEye = [SKAction resizeToHeight:1 duration:.2];
SKAction *delay2 = [SKAction waitForDuration:.5];
SKAction *openEye = [SKAction resizeToHeight:3 duration:.2];

SKAction *all = [SKAction sequence:@[delay,blinkEye, delay2,openEye]]];

//create the lefteye object
lefteye = [[Eye alloc] init...]; 
//create the righteye object
righteye = [[Eye alloc] init...];
[lefteye repeatActionForever:all];
```

Comment: So where can I use it?